# Adding Master ID To the Child

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I need some help. I am the beginner on web scraping.
I am working on a website that has more than two levels. 
I can get all the table by python but I can not relate master and child object. I had table as below but I can not add index(i) column to the first table.

How could I add index to my first table as below. Thanks.

I have a master array like;

[1,2,3,4,5]

And i have detail array like this

```
 [1, 2, 3]
 [2, 3, 4]
```

When i getting second array i want to add first levels id to second table/array. How could i add this. I have added my code in the comment area. 
For sample i have two level for loop in my code.

Thanks

Comment: #This is my code and I could not manage to do that. If anybody help I will be gratefull
import numpy as np
a = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [2, 3, 4]
    ])
for i in (range(1,2)):
    for j in range(np.size(a,0)):
        a.append(i)

Answer (score 0):

First I added index in my list

```
table_km_rows=soup2.findAll('table')[0].findAll("tr")
for tr in table_km_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [tr.text.strip() for tr in td if tr.text.strip()]
    if row:
        row=[i+1,row]
        myRelatedCityKMTable.append(row)
```

Then seperate my list to columns

```
df_km=df_km.KM.apply(pd.Series) \
    .merge(df_km, right_index = True, left_index = True) \
    .drop(["KM"], axis =`enter code here` 1)
df_km.columns=["IL","km","ID"]
#now 'age' will appear at the end of our df
df_km = df_km[['ID','IL','km']]
```